# How can I train my neural network model with tow or more .npy files simultaneously?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am a beginner of AlexNet neural network.I'm making an autopilot for a simple racing game.Here is the code I used to train my model with a file named training_data_n1.npy. I currently have three .npy files, so how can I modify my code so that I can train my model with three or more .npy files simultaneously (without merging these .npy files into one .npy file).I would appreciate it if you could provide the code.   :)

```
WIDTH = 102
HEIGHT = 79
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 8
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta5-car-fast-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alexnetv2', EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

train_data = np.load('training_data_n1.npy',allow_pickle=True)
train = train_data[:-50]
test = train_data[-50:]
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that they are all named `'training_data_nXX.npy'` you could try something like this:

```
train_data = np.load('training_data_n1.npy',allow_pickle=True)
for i in range(2,4):
    current_array = np.load('training_data_n'+i+'.npy',allow_pickle=True)
    train_data = np.concatenate((train_data, current_array))
```

if you are limited by your ram or something else, what you could do is repeat your training loop for all of the dataset that you want

```
nb_of_dataset=3
for i in range(1, nb_of_dataset+1)
    train_data = np.load('training_data_n'+i+'.npy',allow_pickle=True)
    train = train_data[:-50]
    test = train_data[-50:]
    X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
    Y = [i[1] for i in train]

    test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
    test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

    model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),
            snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

Comment: Oh my God!!!Your answer is extremely great and helpful ! The use of np.concatenate not only solve this problem.I even felt  upset in the whole afternoon, because I couldn't merge two.npy files properly.BUT YOU GOT IT!Have a good day,sir! :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped !